# Select ALL mail or photos

Tags: settings, email, photos

Is it possible to select all your emails at once in the default mail app of WP8? The same goes for images in the default image library. You have the ability to select all your text messages in the default messaging app, but this doesn't seem possible in the default image library and the mail app.

Comment: Assuming you mean all mails that have been downloaded to the phone? Remember, what is on the phone is at best a subset of what is actually in your inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail no, photos yes. To select all the photos:

- select a gallery like camera roll
- Tap the select button
- Tap the menu button
- Select all